# USB Debugging on Android - Tried everything I can think of

Tags: android, usb, driver

I've been struggling for the past 3 days with trying to get started with USB debugging for android apps. Currently, my phone is not being recognized by my computer at all. Here is what I have already done/tried:

-Enable USB debugging on phone - check

-Restarted all devices - way too many times check

-When I check device manager to update drivers etc, my device doesn't show up under 'Other Devices' or anything related to the phone but instead under 'Human Interface Devices'

-And when I try to update the drivers from there, it will not work, telling me that the drivers are already at the highest.

-When my phone is plugged into my computer, it charges but even the file explorer does not see that it is connected, I have no way to view the phone.

-I have tried 3 different brands of usb/micro-usb cords to see if that was the problem

-I have updated all drivers for my computer

I've tried many many other obscure things as well but if anyone has any ideas please please let me know!

Running an LG-D631 Vista

Comment: have you enabled developer mode in your device?

Comment: what is the version of your android?

Comment: 4.4.2 is what I'm currently running

Comment: I have also tried plugging it into multiple computers, none of them recognize the phone.